# How to add shadow to borderless applications on Gnome

Tags: gnome, themes, gui

I have a borderless application and I want to know is there any way that exists to add shadow to a borderless application on Gnome desktop?

[image]

Comment: Which application is this? It looks like it is missing the window frame; the shadow is applied to the window frame.

Comment: I disabled the window frame. It's Alacritty.

Comment: If you want this level of customization, you should probably use a different DE.  GNOME is designed to be simple, consistent, and easy-to-use.  This comes at the expense of the ability for the end user to easily customize the DE.  It's a feature, not a bug of this DE.  If you want to fine tune and tinker with your desktop experience, you should look at KDE (Kubuntu) or another flavor.  You can "Try Ubuntu" in a live session using installation media before making any commitment.

Comment: Typically the window manager is responsible for creating the window and, of course, the corresponding shadow. You might want to open a bug with Alacritty. I ~think~ they should implement a window with a zero pixel border which might allow the window manager to create the necessary shadow without actually showing the frame. (Although, I'm not sure if it is also possible to create a zero height header bar in Gnome). I know this is not a solution... may be someone else on AskUbuntu has a better option for you.